# High performance plot control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls

I am doing some work for which I need to develop a control, it should be a simple graph that shows several points and two edges.

My problem is that I need to show up to 16k points, with an update rate of 30 Hz. Has anyone done something similar?, and has any advice?.

For example whether to inherit from FrameworkElement or Control (ItemsControl in this case). If the control inherits from FrameworkElememt it may have a better performance drawing the points in the OnRender method but I would miss the Templating feature that comes from inheriting from Control.

Or does there exist another control that can do this out there?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do yo ureally need to update 16.000 poihts all 30 times per second? Or are most not changing?

Comment: On every update all points may change. Also i need to provide zooming so that's why the amount of points that has to be handled. thanks

Comment: Ask yourself first - do you really need Templating? If you develop control for your own needs, I think that answer should be - no!

Comment: How sparse is your graph? Is it connected? What is the average size of a connected component?

Comment: Hm, you can use DirectX and project a DirectX surfact onto a WOF control (fully supported). Rendering a vertex array containing 30.000 points is not even worth mentioning for DirectX. Modern games render hundreds of millions of complete triangles per second. 16.000 points is a mid range special effect ;)

Comment: @alex no is not conected, are just points on a coordinate system. thanks

Comment: @TomTom i asked a question about your suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7357231/763705) (plotting a DirectX surface into WPF) it may be intresting too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using InteropBitmap, it is the fatest bitmap rendering class from WPF.

It allows you to map the image that you want to paint (in memory) and then reder it as a Image. This was perfect as i needed to plot points on the screen.

I got great performance (almost 50Hz for 20k points), i also use PLINQ to update the points in memory.

check [this](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf/) article for more details...

Comment: Hi, the link shows 403 Error. Can you give more information or other link? I'm working in a project and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try and read about [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/tags/zoomablecanvas/). I believe it can solve your problem. You can render all the points as small rectangles/ellipses inside the ZoomableCanvas.

Comment: Have you tryed that control, as what i need most is the performance. thanks

Comment: Yes, some time ago. He also has demos that you can compile and see them work.