# Can a DirectX surface be plotted to a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, directx, rendering

Can DirectX be used to plot a set of points on a WPF control (or something that can be used by WPF).

I need to implement a control in WPF that should plot 16k points with an update rate of 30 Hz, and i'm running out of solutions rigth now.

This idea is from a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7185163/763705) question.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is D3DImage what you're after? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx

Comment: @jeffora i'm really don't know, i have been reading all the docs about D3DImage, and it seems to fit. But how to draw on that control the set of points??

Comment: I'm no expert. You probably want to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785.aspx. In general, I think you need a native DLL to render the DX content (or use a managed wrapper like SlimDX), and then you Lock/SetBackBuffer etc on the D3DImage object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it can. It's usually quite smooth, because WPF itself is an implementation of DirectX.

See MS' Greg Schechter blog:

> [Redirecting GDI, DirectX, and WPF applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greg_schechter/redirecting-gdi-directx-and-wpf-applications)

You can also have a sample of D3DImage on a surface on WPF from Codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/D3DImage.aspx

Comment: Updated link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greg_schechter/redirecting-gdi-directx-and-wpf-applications

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You use `D3DImage`, Texture (`SharpDX` or `SlimDX`) and `Surface`. You need create texture outside your application and update its conent by video driver or by another way. In WPF you create `D3DImage`:

```
Texture = new Texture(Device.DeviceEx, width, height, 1, Usage.RenderTarget, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default, ref handle);
```

Very important is that you foram must be `Format.A8R8G8B8` (it is restriction of WPF):

```
using (var surface = texture.GetSurfaceLevel(0))
        {
            var handle = surface.NativePointer;
            Lock();
                SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, handle);
                Unlock();
        }
```

And after each updating of frame you need only

```
Lock();
                AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, PixelWidth, PixelHeight));
                Unlock();
```

It's better, if you will put your `D3DImage` in separate `Dispatcher`