# Getting a DirectX view/window using WPF?

Tags: c++, wpf, qt, directx, directx-11

I want to have a box (or ideally the contents of one of the WPF panels) contain a DirectX 11 rendered image. I've looked around and found a [one year MS blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/10/29/wpf-in-net-4-6-1/) briefly mention that DirectX11 is possible which links to a [dead GitHub project,](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop) another [MS blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greg_schechter/2006/05/03/redirecting-gdi-directx-and-wpf-applications/) says that it is easy to do but doesn't mention what version of DX it is (i'm betting it's 9). It appears (to me at least) that there is no real solution to get DX11 working as part of WPF application.

**Do you have any resources that might help me?**

**Or should I use Qt since the entire backend of the program will be C++ anyway?**

I have no problem working in Qt since I would have to learn most of either WPF or Qt anyway but i'd prefer to work in WPF since I won't need any of the cross platform functionality and it appears (at first glance) that WPF has better documentation.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7357231/3797758), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095089/wpf-and-directx-11-via-d3dimage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7185163/3797758) all related to getting a DirectX 11 view into a WPF application. I found that the information in these questions doesn't really point to good guides or give useful advice for what I want to do.

Comment: Have you tried to use [WPFDXInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop)?

Answer (score 1):

**The solution known as SlimDX may be of use**: https://slimdx.org/

Some pros: It's a wide-range API wrapper for WPF, supporting D3D9, D3D10, D3D11, XAudio2, etc. It also natively supports .NET 4.0 and x64 targeting. An old WPF project of mine (C# though, not C++) utilizes SlimDX, and my experience with it had been positive.

Some cons: The latest release is January of 2012, so it's no longer in active development.

**The only possible caveat:** I'm not sure how it'll work with C++ (if at all).